# MySQL: Incrementing Id by random groups created

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want my table to auto increment a GroupId for every group created. The groups are created at random from a userInformation Table. The group information table stores the random group id (selected from userInformation table) into its table. So far I have been able to increment it. I just get zeros

```
$GroupSize = $_POST['groupsize'];

//Connect to the Server+Select DB
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbName) or die("Nope");

if (isset($_POST['create'])) {

//assign group id to groups created
//insert groupinformation to table from userInformation


//What I Have Tried
     //$query = "INSERT INTO groupInformation SELECT RegistrationId FROM (Select RegistrationId from userInformation order by RAND() LIMIT ".$GroupSize.")";
    //$query = "INSERT INTO groupInformation(RegistrationId) SELECT RegistrationId FROM (Select * from userInformation order by RAND() LIMIT ".$GroupSize.") AS j";




    $query = "INSERT INTO groupInformation(RandomGroupId,RegistrationId) SELECT randomRegistrationId,RegistrationId FROM (Select *,RAND() AS randomRegistrationId FROM userInformation ORDER BY randomRegistrationId LIMIT ".$GroupSize." ) AS j";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die ("query failed " . mysqli_error($con));



}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Here Are my Tables:

[image: groupInformation]

[image: userInformation]

Here is my current output:

[image: output]

I need the groups to have there random GroupId to increment so like (1004 1003 1000) = 1(RandomGroupId), (1004, 1002, 1000) = 2(RandomGroupId),  ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. i hope it will help you:

$letters = 'abcefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890';
$verificationText =substr(str_shuffle($letters), 0, 10);